# Manga about a girl who runs away to a city and meets a woman who tries to kill her because the girl will kill the woman

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga starts with a kid whose parents just died.  She runs away to the nearby city where she meets a lady who remembers her past life.  The lady tries to kill the girl because the girl is the heroine and the lady will die because of the heroine so the lady is trying to save her own life.  But the heroine ends up killing the lady and inheriting the lady's memories of the story.

She finds out that her parents died for the sake of the story, and she is mad at the world for this.  She tries to change her future, and cuts her hair to look like a boy.  Then she decides to try and become an adventurer in the forest she meets a man who helps her and trains her for a while, then she is left on her own and she continues her journey.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I've tried to clean this up a bit to make it more readable, but I couldn't parse the last sentence.  Is she an adventurer in the fires, or does she meet the man in the fires?  (Is there a period after "adventurer" or after "fires?")  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: This sounds like a good story! Could you perhaps add some of the names of the characters if you remember them? :)

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Otome Game no Heroine de Saikyou Survival](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/otome-game-no-heroine-de-saikyou-survival)*.

> Alicia is an orphan living in Ciel, a world of swords and magic. One day, she discovers that she is "**the heroine of an otome game". Even the death of her parents was simply part of the story**. Alicia decisively rejects the heroine's role as "nonsense". Taking the name "Aria" as an adventurer, she gradually grows into the "Ash-crowned Princess of Slaughter" who wields multiple weapons and magic! But, when she receives a request to escort a "villainess", without realizing it she finds herself caught up in the stage of the game where nobles struggle against each other...? "I am 'me'. I'm not a character in a game!"

Story goes pretty much exactly as you said. Main character is an orphan whose parents were killed by a monster attack; she runs away from the orphanage instead of being sold off, and is attacked by a woman claiming that the protagonist is the heroine of a story. Her plan is to kill her and take her magic stone to absorb her memories, but dies instead.

[image]

[image]

And yes, part of her survival method is to cut her hair short and disguise herself as a boy.